# How to specify unknown number of preceding indices in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am keeping either `(n_features, 3)` or `(n_samples, n_features, 3)` inside an array.

Is it possible to address 2nd dimension from the end implicitly, without knowing number of preceeding dimensions?

Currently I wrote

```
def get_feature(data, i):
   n = data.ndim
   if n == 2:
      return data[i,:]
   elif n == 3:
      return data[:,i,:]
   elif n == 4:
      return data[:,:,i,:]
   else:
      raise NotImplementedError
```

How to shorten?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [*Ellipsis*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) to skip first few dimensions:

```
data[...,i,:]
```

---

*Example*:

```
a = np.arange(24).reshape(2,2,2,3)
b = np.arange(24).reshape(2,4,3)
c = np.arange(24).reshape(8,3)

(a[...,1,:] == a[:,:,1,:]).all()
# True

(b[...,1,:] == b[:,1,:]).all()
# True

(c[...,1,:] == c[1,:]).all()
# True
```

It correctly index arrays of different dimensions.